# error while importing maya.standalone in nuke

Tags: python-2.7, nuke

I was thinking to write a script, that would open maya in standalone mode and list out certain attributes of lights in maya , from inside the nuke. Inorder to do that, i need to import maya.standalone module and use mayapy to open the file using subprocess module to call external shell command. To be very honest, i am not sure, if this is the right way to do it from nuke. Would be great , if someone can point if what , i am doing wrong.

```html
import sys
mayaLibPath="C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Maya2014\Python\Lib\site-packages"
mayaDllPath="C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Maya2014\Python\DLLs"
sys.path.append(mayaLibPath)
sys.path.append(mayaDllPath)
import maya.cmds
import maya.standalone
```

I get following error, when i am running above script.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 7, in 
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.

Cheers !!

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape your backslash when using a string literal. You could also replace with forward slash instead. But a backslash on its own is an escape character, like `\n` or `\t`

```
import sys
mayaLibPath="C:\\Program Files\\Autodesk\\Maya2014\\Python\\Lib\\site-packages"
mayaDllPath="C:\\Program Files\\Autodesk\\Maya2014\\Python\\DLLs"
sys.path.append(mayaLibPath)
sys.path.append(mayaDllPath)
import maya.cmds
import maya.standalone
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out :)
.but that still doesn't solve the problem...it still shows the same dll load failed error.